# Poco DateTimeFormatter - Print timestamp with current timezone

Tags: c++, datetime, locale, unix-timestamp, poco-libraries

How do I print a `Poco::Timestamp` with `Poco::DateTimeFormatter` into a formatted date-time based on the current timezone?

I have a `print_pretty_datetime(const Poco::Timestamp &now)` where I'll receive a `Poco::Timestamp` so I can't use a `Poco::LocalDateTime` unfortunately.

MCVE:

```
#include "Poco/Timestamp.h"
#include "Poco/Timezone.h"
#include "Poco/DateTimeFormatter.h"
#include "Poco/DateTimeFormat.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Cannot change the method signature. I will receive a Poco::Timestamp object
std::string print_pretty_datetime(const Poco::Timestamp &now)
{
    return Poco::DateTimeFormatter::format(
       now,
       Poco::DateTimeFormat::SORTABLE_FORMAT,
       Poco::Timezone::tzd()
     );
}


int main()
{
     Poco::Timestamp now;
     std::string dt_now = print_pretty_datetime(now);

     std::cout << dt_now << '\n';

     return 0;
}
```

E.g: the string returned is `2019-01-07 11:10:12` (thus `UTC+0`) whereas my device is in in `UTC+1`.

In fact, the command `date` returns `Mon Jan 7 12.10.12 CET 2019`.

What is the correct parameter for `tzd` in `Poco::DateTimeFormatter::format` for printing the date-time based on current locale?

---

System info:

```
SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Poco 1.9.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Poco::LocalDateTime` in the system's current timezone from a `Poco::Timestamp` via an intermediate `Poco::DateTime` object.

```
#include "Poco/LocalDateTime.h"
#include "Poco/DateTime.h"
#include "Poco/DateTimeFormat.h"
#include "Poco/DateTimeFormatter.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Poco::Timestamp ts;
    Poco::DateTime dt(ts);
    Poco::LocalDateTime ldt(dt);

    std::string str = Poco::DateTimeFormatter::format(ldt, Poco::DateTimeFormat::SORTABLE_FORMAT);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cool, couldn't figure out the passage from `Timestamp` to `LocalDateTime`

Answer (score 2):

Get local time by `Poco::LocalDateTime`, then read its timestemp and pass it into formatter:

```
Poco::LocalDateTime dateTime;
Poco::Timestamp now = dateTime.timestamp();
```

---

You need to define your own string format which includes information about time-zone, because SORTABLE_FORMAT doesn't handle it.

Hint (you can open source of `DateTimeFormatter` and see how `timeZoneDifferential` is processed in `append` function - this parameter doesn't affect *hours* in output).
So if you change to:

```
 std::string dt_now = Poco::DateTimeFormatter::format(
   now,
   "%H:%M:%S %z,%Z",
   Poco::Timezone::tzd()
 );
```

you will see `HH::MM::SS +01:00,+0100` in output.

Comment: hey good point (I have also mentioned it in my answer). I have edited my question as it wasn't clear enough. I have no control over the `Timestamp`: It's a parameter I will receive in my function, so based on it I have to print the current date-time

Answer (score 0):

Alright, if you don't necessarily need to use a `Poco::Timestamp`, a solution can be simply to use a `Poco::LocalDateTime`:

```
#include "Poco/LocalDateTime.h"
#include "Poco/DateTimeFormatter.h"
#include "Poco/DateTimeFormat.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    Poco::LocalDateTime now;

    std::string dt_now = Poco::DateTimeFormatter::format(
      now,
      Poco::DateTimeFormat::SORTABLE_FORMAT
    );

    std::cout << dt_now << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

and this will print the date based on the current timezone.

I still have to use the `Poco::Timestamp` though as I'll get it as parameter to my `print_pretty_datetime(const pc::Timestamp &now)`, so this answer does not yet applies to my case.